# Function not Splitting String by"\t"

Tags: python, split

for every line in a list i am trying to split it into three components which are separated by "\t", however this code is is not splitting by "t". Instead is splitting the entire line up by letter.

```
# Function to load a set of sequences from a given file
# File should be stored as a sequence per line
# Input: File name containing sequences 
# Output: List of all sequences in that file
def LoadSeq(FileName):
    FileIn = open(FileName, "r")
    SeqList = []
    for Line in FileIn:
        Line = Line.rstrip()
        SeqList.append(Line)
    FileIn.close()
    return SeqList

def LineToList(Str):
    Str = Str.rsplit()
    return Str.split("\t")

import math

def CalculateDistance(Lat1, Lon1, Lat2, Lon2):
    Lat1 = float(Lat1)
    Lon1 = float(Lon1)
    Lat2 = float(Lat2)
    Lon2 = float(Lon2)
    nDLat = (Lat1 - Lat2) * 0.017453293
    nDLon = (Lon1 - Lon2) * 0.017453293
    Lat1 = Lat1 * 0.017453293
    Lat2 = Lat2 * 0.017453293
    nA = (math.sin(nDLat/2) ** 2) + math.cos(Lat1) * math.cos(Lat2) * (math.sin(nDLon/2) ** 2 )
    nC = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(nA),math.sqrt( 1 - nA ))
    nD = 6372.797 * nC
    return nD

def LocationCount(FileName, DesiredDistance, DesiredLat, DesiredLong):
    for Line in LoadSeq(FileName):
        LineToList(Line)
        Counter = 0
        CalculateDistance(Seq[1], Seq[2], DesiredLat, DesiredLong)
        if CalculateDistance <= DesiredDistance:
             Counter += 1
    return Counter

NumberInDistance = LocationCount("Mammal.txt", 20, 50.261667, -5.043333)
print(NumberInDistance)
```

This is the code i have been using, i am not spliting it right or am i messing it up further along? I have to use Python and it has to stay in as similar forrmatting as this if possible

Comment: Hey can you please help us with a sample input file? And, how does your current output look like?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to upload a sample document for you to try it out on

Answer (score 2):

You have first called `rsplit` (with no specific separator defined) that will [splits the string on any whitespace char](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit). Afterward you are calling `split` on list (returned by `rsplit`) that will results into exception.

If you want to split only by tab you have to delete first line in your LineToList.

```
def LineToList(Str):
    return Str.split("\t")
```

Comment: Okay have adjusted for this, but not it is coming up with
    Traceback (most recent call last): line 52, in <module>
    NumberInDistance = LocationCount("Mammal.txt", 20, 50.261667, -5.043333)
    line 46, in LocationCount
    Dist =  CalculateDistance(Seq[Counter+1], Seq[Counter+2], DesiredLat, DesiredLong)
    IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @NicoleKing Can you please give me 1 or 2 lines of `mammal.txt` ?

Comment: Myotis nattereri 54.07663633 -1.006446707
Myotis nattereri 54.25637837 -1.002130504
Myotis nattereri 54.25637837 -1.002130504
Myotis nattereri 54.25637837 -1.002130504
Myotis nattereri 53.95498846 -0.920178777
Pipistrellus pipistrellus sensu lato 56.12259134 -4.49369336
Pipistrellus pipistrellus sensu lato 56.08071489 -4.563323198
Pipistrellus pipistrellus sensu lato 55.89753176 -4.279250374
Myotis daubentonii 52.24773003 -1.084432324
Myotis daubentonii 52.3648261 -1.111389624
Myotis daubentonii 52.40067491 -1.095969578
Myotis daubentonii 52.45438582 -1.065434228

Comment: @NicoleKing I found that in record 3, 5, 11, there is space instead of tab. Please make sure that for separation there must be a tab (no space).

Answer (score 1):

In your function `LineToList`, first you call [**`.rsplit()`**](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html), which converts the string parameter into a list. Then you proceed to call *another* `.split()`, which would result in an error, since you can only call `.split()` on a string.

Instead, change your function to:

```
def LineToList(Str):
    return Str.replace("\t", " ").rsplit()
```

Which changes the `'\t'` to a `' '`, thus enabling it to identification by the `.rsplit()`.

---

```
>>> def LineToList(Str):
...     return Str.replace("\t", " ").rsplit()
... 
>>> LineToList("hi\tthis\tis\tdata")
['hi', 'this', 'is', 'data']
>>>
```